# How to move files from a computer connected via SSH to a VPS?

Tags: linux, ssh, cmd, scp, vps

I know that scp is frequently used to move files between servers, but I'm not sure how I can reference my computer as a server. If scp is the right command to do this then what am I missing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just scp /some/local/file youruser@yourremoteserver:/remote/path

Reverse the two arugments to copy a remote file to local.

Comment: Are you saying that the source file location is on the computer and not the VPS?

Comment: It would help if you would more clearly specify what you are trying to do.

Comment: I thought the title was rather clear. If it helps explain my comment, I thought scp used file locations from the open directory in SSH and the remote directory. Does scp use locations on my computer rather than in the SSH cmd?

Comment: scp is unrelated to ssh other than using to as the low level transmission protocol.

Comment: What is the default directory for the local file then?

Comment: Whatever directory your're in in your local shell.

Comment: You're saying I need to try scp from a location other than the SSH cmd... can't believe how dull I can be sometimes.

Comment: Yes. You run scp on the local machine, not the remote machine (Well, you could, but home machines tend to be a pain to reach due to NAT, etc)